# login to facebook in my website - javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am working in the task of login to facebook from my website, i got the code from here [github](https://github.com/SoldierCorp/Login-with-Facebook-SDK-for-JavaScript).
here is the code:

```
    $(function() {

    var app_id = my_app_id;
    var scopes = 'email, user_friends, user_online_presence';

    var btn_login = '<a href="#" id="login" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</a>';

    var div_session = "<div id='facebook-session'>"+
                      "<strong></strong>"+
                      "<img>"+
                      "<a href='#' id='logout' class='btn btn-danger'>Log Out</a>"+
                      "</div>";

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            alert("init");

        FB.init({
            appId      : app_id,
            status     : true,
            cookie     : true, 
            xfbml      : true, 
            version    : 'v2.1'
        });


        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response, function() {});
        });
    };

    var statusChangeCallback = function(response, callback) {
        console.log(response);

        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            getFacebookData();
        } else {
            callback(false);
        }
    }

    var checkLoginState = function(callback) {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            callback(response);
        });
    }

    var getFacebookData =  function() {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            $('#login').after(div_session);
            $('#login').remove();
            $('#facebook-session strong').text("welcome: "+response.name);
            $('#facebook-session img').attr('src','http://graph.facebook.com/'+response.id+'/picture?type=large');
        });
    }

    var facebookLogin = function() {
        checkLoginState(function(data) {
            if (data.status !== 'connected') {
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.status === 'connected'){
                        getFacebookData();
                    }
                }, {scope: scopes});
            }
        })
    }

    var facebookLogout = function() {
        checkLoginState(function(data) {
            if (data.status === 'connected') {
                FB.logout(function(response) {
                    $('#facebook-session').before(btn_login);
                    $('#facebook-session').remove();
                })
            }
        })

    }



    $(document).on('click', '#login', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        facebookLogin();
    })

    $(document).on('click', '#logout', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (confirm("Are you sure"))
            facebookLogout();
        else 
            return false;
    })

})
```

I made an account on facebook developers and got the id which i put in the code (my_app_id), the problem is that when i login with another account, the response object returned gives me "not_authorized" status.
I want to be able to login with any account and get the info i want (like user_name, profile_picture, etc...). I got these information only when i login with the account that i created on the facebook developers.
Another problem is here:

```
var facebookLogin = function() {
    checkLoginState(function(data) {
        if (data.status !== 'connected') {alert("facebookLogin");
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected'){
                    getFacebookData();
                }
            }, {scope: scopes});
        }
    })
}
```

it gets the facebook data when i am logged in the account, where is the condition where the account is not logged in.
I mean there is a line checks if the user is logged in `if (data.status !== 'connected')`, where is the else condition the verify that the user is not logged in?

Comment: don´t use jquery for the most basic things. this article should teach you how it works: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: btw, "user_online_presence" does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you start your testing by using the latest APIs and guides in our [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.3) in a blank page/project without jQuery or other third-party libraries.

Once everything is setup and working, start adding other libraries and see how it goes.

Moreover, if you are having issues testing your app with different accounts, it's most likely because your app is on **Development Mode** and the account you are testing with is not added in the app's role and hence they cannot actually access your app. Try add the other accounts as `admin`, `developer` or `tester` and test again: `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{APP-ID}/roles/`